# Sum the first element of each group and with RunningValue

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report on SSRS with a Dataset that have these 3 Fields:

```
Fields!MyFirstField.Value
Fields!MySecondField.Value
Fields!MyThirdField.Value
```

The report is divided into a group:
In my Row files I have

```
MyPrimaryGroup
  MySeconday Group
```

And I have the Field that makes each group:

```
Fields!Group.Value
```

The idea is to accumulate the first element of each group of each field.

What I did was the following:

```
Dim Acum as Double
Dim ActualGroup = ""
Function Accumulator(ByVal MyGroup as String, ByVal value as Double) As Double


If ActualGroup <> MyGroup
    Acum= Acum + value
    ActualGroup = MyGroup 
    Return Acum
    value=0
End If


End Function
```

After this I made a calculated field like this:

```
=Code.Accumulator(Fields!Group.Value,Fields!MyFirstField.Value)
```

And put it in a row inside my primary group, the thing is, it is only accumulating the first two, for example:

In this image we have a graphical example, what the code is doing is saving the first element of each group so in this case the Accumulated value should be `10+11+12=33` but the code is giving me `21`, is not saving the third value onwards]

[image]

This is one part of the problem, the other problem is that I cant make this accumulator work with a field that have a running value expression, for example:

```
FormatNumber(RunningValue(Fields!MySecondField.Value, Sum,"MyDataset"), 2)
```

Is there any way to sum the first element of each group and accumulate its value, the same with a field that is in fact a running value?

To Give you more info about what I what to achieve, I screenshot the table:
[image]

Where you see blue circles, is in those Fields inside my group that I want to put the code and MyField3 is the running value and these are the groups:
[image]

This is more or less the info I have for the first two elements of my group:
[image]

So the code should:

```
If MERCH308 <> "" then
0 = 0 + 6,80
"" = MERCH308
End If
```

On the next group it should do:

```
If MERCH314 <> MERCH308
6,80 = 6,80 + 22,28
MERCH308 = MERCH314
End If
```

And By the next one:

```
If MERCH314 <> MERCH314
//It does not enter the if
```

Until it sees a new group different from MERCH314, the problem is, that the only way for the code to function properly (as I investigated further) is to unmark the page break in the tablix and mark the "Maintain everything in one page if possible".

And what Im trying to say with the runningvalue problem is the following:

MyFields3 is a running value:

```
=FormatNumber(RunningValue(Fields!MyFields3.Value, Sum,"MyDataset",2)
```

But I can't Apply:

```
Code.Accumulator(Fields!MyGroup.Value,RunningValue(Fields!MyFields3.Value,Sum,"Mydataset")
```

As it says "have an incorrect number as a parameter for the function RunningValue"

So the idea is to accumulate the 1st element of each group of an accumulator as "RunningValue" is in fact, an accumulator, so the idea is to sum (for my third column) the 6,80 + 29,08. But Remember that 29,08 is the result of a runningvalue.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem with Page Break.
If anyone have the same problem, you must declare your variables as Public Shared as each page break is a new instance and being Public Shared your values will persist.
Now onto the problem with the runningvalue

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the first part of your problem so my answer is partial cause I don't get your issue with running value field, so I am trying to guess what you need.

You have to go to `report / report properties / code` tab and add the following code:

```
Dim public total as Integer 
Dim public prevgroup as String = ""

Public Function AddTotal(ByVal group as String,ByVal value AS Integer ) AS Integer 
    If (group <> prevgroup) Then
        total = total + value
        prevgroup = group
        return total
    End If
    return 0                
End Function 

Public Function GetTotal() 
    return total
End Function
```

This is a guess of data arrangement you have.

[image]

Use this expression in to get the sum of the first values of every distinct group:

```
=Code.GetTotal()
```

Use this one to get the running value:

```
=Code.AddTotal(Fields!Group.Value,Fields!Value.Value)
```

It will preview:

[image]

The red rectangle represent my dataset, the other data is added by expressions.

---

**UPDATE:**  Running value of first values based on user specification.

Let me know if this was helpful.

You can achieve this by adding row number to your dataset query.

```
select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 1)) as row_num,
    *
from CTE
```

Note I am just adding row number and selecting all fields from CTE.
This is my dataset:

[image]

Modify the `AddTotal` function as follows

```
Dim public total as Integer 
Dim public prevgroup as String = ""

Public Function AddTotal(ByVal group as String,ByVal value AS Integer, ByVal nextGroup As String ) AS Integer 
    If (group <> prevgroup) Then
        total = total + value
        prevgroup = group
    End If

    If (group <> nextGroup) Then
        return total
    End If
    return 0         
End Function
```

Configure your tablix as below:

[image]

In the expression set the following code:

```
=Code.AddTotal(Fields!Group.Value,Fields!Value.Value,
lookup(Fields!row_num.Value + 1,Fields!row_num.Value,Fields!Group.Value,"DataSet5")
)
```

Select the expression row and set the `Row visibility` setting with the following code:

```
=Iif(Code.AddTotal(Fields!Group.Value,Fields!Value.Value,
lookup(Fields!row_num.Value + 1,Fields!row_num.Value,Fields!Group.Value,"DataSet5")
)=0,True,False)
```

This will preview the below tablix:

[image]

Comment: Hey there Alejandro, I updated my initial thread with a bunch tons of more information.

Comment: That is a great Idea, is there any way to make the same with RowNumber instead of changing the query?

Comment: @Nickso : No, my approach uses `lookup` for get the next row group value. `Lookup` looks for a row in the dataset (RowNumber cannot be used as parameter or parameter expression of lookup function) and returns other column value in that row specified by user. I think this is the only way to know the future row of a dataset. Share your SQL query to help you adding row number, that is simple though

Comment: It is a huge Query as it's a Dynamic Query